# Perform animation after ActionSheet Disappears

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, delay, uiactionsheet

I have a board game, and I am using action sheet to undo the move. I am able to undo the move and animate the piece from current to previous position.

But due to less space, I am using action sheet for user to select undo option.

But the problem is when the user selects undo, animation is done before the action sheet disappears.

I can delay the animation, but there are a few other elements on the board, which are updated and all of this is done before the action sheet disappears.

Can someone advice what approach should I follow to solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to call your logic in this method `- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;` it is a delegate of ActionSheet and will call after dismissing Action sheet.

Comment: superb :), it was all I needed, thanks ;). I'll accept this as an answer when you'll submit your Answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform your logic in this method

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

it is a delegate of ActionSheet and will call after dismissing Action sheet.